# Custom authentication adapter in ADFS as a primary step

Tags: .net, authentication, single-sign-on, adfs, multi-factor-authentication

We have a setup which involves a third party web application using [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) as its access control server. That worked well for a while.

Now we need to install a custom Authentication Policy in `ADFS`, in order to delegate the authentication process to yet another custom, in-house built server and employ custom, dynamic rules.

From our understanding, this is a bird's eye view of the general ADFS authentication pipeline:

[image]

Basically, it's quite easy to augment the authentication process with a custom, secondary step but it's impossible to skip the `Primary` authentication sub process.

We did manage to implement a `Multi Factor Authentication Adapter` (basically a .NET assembly which subscribes to the `ADFS` conventions) and successfully install it within our `ADFS`:
[image]

Unfortunately, our situation requires us to customize the very first step and react differently to various scenarios. For instance:

- *maybe* host a custom login form which validates credentials with the `AD`
- *maybe* react to a custom-built, non `ADFS` `OAuth` access token
- etc

Having the end user be forced to provide credentials from the get go is a deal breaker.

Does anyone have an idea about how this could be achieved?

We're using `ADFS` on `Windows Server 2012 R2`. This version of `ADFS` doesn't require `IIS` to be preinstalled.

We found an interesting article regarding `ADFS 2.0` which is much older than what we're using and requires `IIS`. The article provides an example of how to alter the sign in page of what seems to be the primary authentication step:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1600.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-local-authentication-type.aspx

We didn't manage to replicate that example on our `ADFS`.

Comment: What you are trying is not possible. Adfs on 2012 r2 has set primary auth providers that you can't change or customise. The wiki is merely discussing how to sort the order of auth handlers. Your best bet is to use another Idp as a claims provider trust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @maweeras, you can't for ADFS 3.0 and greater.

ADFS 2.1 and below ran on IIS so you had access to the web site and could make changes in the code.

This lead to people introducing all kinds of security holes for which ADFS got blamed so it was locked down.

As per the suggestion, federate e.g. with identityserver which is open source and do the changes there.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ADFS Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/whats-new-active-directory-federation-services-windows-server), this feature was implemented in ADFS for Windows 2019.

> **External Auth Providers as Primary** - Customers can now use 3rd party authentication products as the first factor and not expose passwords as the first factor. In the cases where an external auth provider can prove 2 factors it can claim MFA.